# Apt-get not found error on ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04

I was running few commands and suddenly my `apt-get` command stopped working, reporting `command not found` error.

Kindly help. I am blocked due to this.

I tried commands from this answer - [askubuntu question for unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what exactly it is which you are running and what the error is.

Answer (score -1):

"Command not found" is the common response for a command you're not authorized to use.  In this case, apt-get is a system command, and requires root privilege; you should type `sudo apt-get` and whatever you're trying to install, remove, etc.  You'll be prompted for your user password, and assuming your'e on the sudoers list, the command will then execute with root privilege.

Comment: even for root it is not working

Comment: It would return permission denied anyway...

Comment: @Zanna with the information we have, I don't know how you can predict that.  Use of sudo, in my experience, lets the sudoer do anything a logged-in root could do (if such a thing still existed in as-distributed Ubuntu).

Comment: I mean, try it, if you run `apt-get` without `sudo` it will not return command not found, but, permission denied etc

Comment: On my Kubuntu installations, both 14.04 and 16.04, if I type a command I don't have the privilege for, I get the "not found" version of the error.  "Permission denied" occurs when I try to do things like write to a folder I don't own.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Can you give an example of such a command that does that? I am curious and would like to try it on my machine.

Comment: Not at the moment; I'm at work, not near my Kubuntu systems.

Comment: Wrong. Super-user commands can still be discovered by regular users. More specifically, `apt-get` has commands and modes that don't require super-user privileges at all. -1